# Duplicated GlobalKey in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart, square

I use Square for in-app payments and in my example I want to redirect user to a dashboard after successful purchase.

So this is the code which I use:

```
void _onCardEntryComplete() {
    var user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context);
    if (_chargeServerHostReplaced) {
      showAlertDialog(
          context: BuySheet.scaffoldKey.currentContext,
          title: "Your order was successful")
    }
    user.updateDashboard(user.user.id);
    user.navigateToNewPage(Dashboard(), context);
  }
```

I am getting redirected to `Dashboard` but if I want to access Purchase again:

```
childButtons.add(UnicornButton(
          hasLabel: true,
          labelText: "Buy stuff",
          currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "buystuff",
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            mini: true,
            child: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
            onPressed: () {
              user.navigateToNewPage(Payment(), context);
            },
          )));
```

I get an error message that GlobalKey is duplicated in widget tree.

If I comment `user.navigateToNewPage(Dashboard(), context);` then it works fine. But the thing is, I want explicitly user to be redirected to a dashboard after successful purchase.

I don't have `GlobalKey` defined in `Dashboard`... It is defined in `Payment`:

```
class Payment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentState createState() => _PaymentState();
}

class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool applePayEnabled = false;
  bool googlePayEnabled = false;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSquarePayment();
  }
```

Comment: Is `Dashboard` and `Payment` are different classes or part of the same class? I guess I know what to do, but I am just making sure of some details. Let me know

Comment: They are different classes.

Comment: Remove `static` from `static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

Comment: I need it in another classes as well. For example - `context: BuySheet.scaffoldKey.currentState.context`. If I remove `static` then it is not reachable.